# "req.user" Appears to be unresolved but isn't

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm currently working on an Express.js application and I'm using Passport.js (and specifically passport-local) for authentication into what's going to be an administration panel.

As of right now, the program does indeed work. I have my app.js that initializes passport and sets the proper sessions etc. I also have my routes going to a separate file in my routes folder from the app.js file.

I'm not sure if this is a bug with Jetbrain's IntelliJ Idea/WebStorm or if I am following bad code practices, but I am getting a "Unresolved variable user" error in my IDE when I call "req.user" in my index.js file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SddFd.png (Can't post images due to reputation)

In my index.ejs file, I am also getting a similar error in my IDE.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IksZ7.png

Even though these 2 issues are showing, the "req.user" variable still consists of data and I am able to successfully check if "user" exists in my ejs file and output the adequate information (when logged in.)

In my app.js file, I am able to call the "req.user" variable without the IDE showing any unknown variable error (https://i.stack.imgur.com/9w7G5.png, line 48), so I am under the belief that I probably did not setup my routes properly.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Hey! Welcome to StackOverflow! No need to insert images of code, just paste your code directly here, it will be much easier to read and/or copy your code, and people will be more eager to help.

Comment: Thanks and yeah sorry about that. The only issue with posting the code is that you wouldn't see the error the IDE is throwing (as it appears to be an issue with intelliJ or something.)

Comment: That is true, that can be left as an image then :)

Answer (score 0):

An IDE like webstorm/intelliJ/textmate/sublime tries to help you with the information you provided it. Since you are using passport, `req.user` might be populated, but intelliJ doesn't know that it is. You can help your IDE by providing additional typings like [@typings/passport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/passport).

Comment: I already added passport and passport-local to the typings. It's pretty weird but it's not a big deal I guess. Maybe the IntelliJs support site might be better to ask these questions. Thanks anyways though.